# Why I can't start a thread 2x in my Activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I push a web service call in my activity to a thread (shown below). The first time I do this in the activity it works fine (gets the text from my edittext and loads the service to get lat/lng data)

But when I click the back button (emulator) and try to fire off this thread a second time it blows up after the .start(); in my click handler. What might I be doing wrong here? thanks

```
private Thread getLocationByZip = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            EditText filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
            Editable zip = filterText.getText();

            LocationLookupService locationLookupService = new LocationLookupService();
            selectedLocation = locationLookupService.getLocationByZip(zip.toString());

            locationHandler.post(launchFindWithLocationInfo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};

private Runnable launchFindWithLocationInfo = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Intent abc = new Intent(LocationLookup.this, FindWithLocation.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);

    locationHandler = new Handler();
    findViewById(R.id.findbyzip).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getLocationByZip.start();
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**

After the great advice I went with an AsyncTask so if anyone finds this going forward the above thread/handler model looks something like the below as an asynctask

```
private class LocationLookupTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Location> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LocationLookup.this, "", "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Location doInBackground(String... zips) {
        Location selectedLocation = null;
        for (String zip : zips) {
            LocationLookupService locationLookupService = new LocationLookupService();
            selectedLocation = locationLookupService.getLocationByZip(zip);
        }
        return selectedLocation;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Location location) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();

        ((AppDelegate) getApplicationContext()).setSelectedLocation(location);
        Intent abc = new Intent(LocationLookup.this, FindWithLocation.class);
        startActivity(abc);
    }
}
```

Now to call this in the onclick you would do this

```
findViewById(R.id.findbyzip).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
                Editable zip = filterText.getText();

                LocationLookupTask task = new LocationLookupTask();
                task.execute(new String[]{zip.toString()});
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't start a thread twice:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once.

Taken from [Thread.start()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29).

So, you need to create a new thread and start that one.

Comment: @Toran - Easiest would be to create a `public class LocationZipThread extends Thread { ... }`. Then you can make as much threads as you need. But, you should use AsyncTask here.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call twice the start method of the Thread class, I suggest you also control the logic within the method onCreate since according to the life cycle of an Activity that method may be called by Android lifecycle Activity Manager.

Furthermore i suggest you to avoid this approach and consider to use the AsyncTask provided by the Android SDK.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this without creating a new class or using `AsyncTask`, you could just make a method to get a new `Thread` on each call:

```
private Thread getLocationByZip;

private void getLocation() {
    getLocationByZip = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                EditText filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
                Editable zip = filterText.getText();

                LocationLookupService locationLookupService = new LocationLookupService();
                selectedLocation = locationLookupService.getLocationByZip(zip.toString());

                locationHandler.post(launchFindWithLocationInfo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
    getLocationByZip.start();
}
```

Then replace `getLocationByZip.start()` in your code with `getLocation()`. However, I agree that an `AsyncTask` would be a better way to go, though this would work for you.

Comment: It should be, since nothing is being modified, and he's only using it with getText(). To be on the super-safe side, he could pass the method a String with the text already retrieved, but I don't think it will matter here.